# How many digits does the number $(8^{28})(5^{80})$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many digits does the number $(8^{28})(5^{80})$ have?

I tried using congurence modulo but was unable to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

The number is $2^410^{80}$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $10=2\cdot 5$.  You can find a high power of $10$ in your number.  What is left?  Modulo won't help for number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

The number $8^{28} \cdot 5^{80}$ can be rewritten as $2^{84} \cdot 5^{80}$. Dividing by $10^{80}$ then gives $2^4=16$, which has $2$ digits, so the number $8^{28} \cdot 5^{80}$ has $82$ digits.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that $8=2^3\implies 8^k=2^{3k}$, thus we see
$$8^{28}\cdot 5^{80}=2^{84}\cdot5^{80}=2^4\cdot(2\cdot5)^{80}=16\cdot10^{80}$$

If you're unsure on digit calculation of that, consider how many digits $16\cdot10^t$ would have for small $t$ and find a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

$8^{28}*5^{80}= (2^3)^{28}*5^{80} = 2^{84}*5^{80}= 2^4(2*5)^{80} = 16*10^{80} = 16\underbrace{000000.....0}_{80\text{ zeros}}$.

But why do it the easy way when you can do it the hard way?

If $M$ is a number with $k$ digits then $10^{k-1}$ is the smallest number with $k$ digits and $\underbrace{99999....9}_{k\text{ nines}}=10^k -1$ is the largest number with $k$ digits.

So $10^{k-1} \le M \le 10^k-1 < 10^k$.

So $\log_{10}(10^{k-1}) \le log_{10} M < \log_{10} 10^k$ so

$k-1 \le \log_{10}M < k$.

So to find out how many digits something has

1) To the log base $10$ of $M$.

2) Take the first integer that is larger than $\log_{10} M$.

So the number of digits of $8^{28}*5^{80}$:

$\log_{10} 8^{28} * 5^{80} =$

$\log_{10} 8^{28}  + \log_{10} 5^{80} =$

$28\cdot \log_{10} 8 + 80\cdot \log_{10} 5\approx $

$28\cdot 0.903 + 80\cdot 0.699 \approx $

$25.3 + 55.9\approx 81.2$ and the next integer larger than that is $82$.

So $8^{28} * 5^{80}$ has $82$ digits.